# How did Abraham perform brit milah?

Tags: technology, brit-milah, abraham

Abraham (around 1800 BC) performed circumcision.
At that period, what tool must he have used to do that?

Also, Genesis 18:7-8 says he cooked a calf. What tool must he have used to kill the calf at such an old time?

Comment: Why do you ask about how Abraham killed the calf and not about Abel or Noah?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=swords+from+1800bce&oq=swords+from+1800bce&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.9291j0j4&client=ms-android-polaroid&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @rosends i didn't know abel or noah killed calf. killing with a sharp object seems ok, but killing with a flat stone like object seems merciless

Comment: Why not assume they just used a knife? It may have been pre-cell phone days, but that doesn't mean they didn't have any tools. Per a quick search, the Iron Age began around 1200 BC and the Bronze Age was 2000 years bfore that, so even if you follow those numbers, Abraham would have had plenty of tools he could have used.

Comment: Bronze must be used. i am assuming how abraham cooked a calf, because killing such a huge animal without sharp tools is a hard task.

Comment: @suhailvs Avraham lived from 1948-2123 AM, which is the same as 1811-1636 BCE. Based on Salmononius2’s numbers, that puts him squarely in the Bronze Age. Do you have any evidence that bronze was insufficient for the job, or even stone for that matter, a tool used elsewhere for Bris Milah (Shemos 4)?

Answer (score 6):

The description of Abraham's circumcision in the Bible doesn't say what tool he used. However, Joshua is described as having circumcised the Israelites with swords of stone (Joshua 5:2), and, as [רבות מחשבות](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16354/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA) notes, Zipporah also used a rock to circumcise her son (Exodus 4:25), so Abraham probably used something similar.

The text also doesn't describe what tool he used to kill the calf, but in the description of the binding of Isaac, he brought a knife (Genesis 22:10), so that is probably what he used for slaughtering.